# Renumbering a Two-Column Multienumerate List

Tags: numbering, enumerate, two-column, multicolumn, columns

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxx{This is the first sentence.}{This is the second sentence.---which I want numbered 1.}
\mitemxx{This is the third sentence.---which I want numbered 2.}{And this is the fourth sentence.---which I want numbered 2.}
\mitemxx{This is the fifth sentence.---which I want numbered 3.}{This is the last sentence.---which I want numbered 3.}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

For the purpose of pairing---How may I renumber the display so that the first item of each column is numbered 1. ; the second item of each column is numbered 2. ; and the third item of each column is numbered 3. (and so forth, if there were more entries)?

Also, how may a heading for each column be introduced? Is there a better way to accomplish this than using `multienumerate`?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to display parallel text? In that case there are several packages available, see the [parallel](https://ctan.org/topic/parallel) topic on CTAN. From that list the most well-known are paracol (see [tagged questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paracol) and reledpar ([questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reledpar)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment it may be better to use a package for parallel columns, there are [several options](https://ctan.org/topic/parallel) to choose from.

However, for a quick fix you can modify the implementation of `\mitemxx` to prevent increasing the counter for the second column.

Internally `\mitemxx` calls another macro `\itemxx`, which prints the actual columns as a sequence of label, content, label, content. In between the two label/content pairs you can add the command `\addtocounter{multienumi}{-1}` that will undo the counter increment caused by the first label.

Note that this only affects the first level of the enumerate, if you have a nested list this will not work properly. To account for that case would require more complex changes in the package code, which would prevent this answer from being a quick fix :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multienum}
% definition modified from the source in multienum.sty
\renewcommand{\itemxx}[2]{\parbox[t]%
{\labelwidth}{\hfill{\labelname}}\hskip\labelsep
\parbox[t]{.5\remainxx}{\raggedright #1}%
\addtocounter{multienumi}{-1}%
\hfill\parbox[t]%
{\labelwidth}{\hfill{\labelname}}\hskip\labelsep
\parbox[t]{0.5\remainxx}{\raggedright #2}\smallskip}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxx{This is the first sentence.}{This is the second sentence.---which I want numbered 1.}
\mitemxx{This is the third sentence.---which I want numbered 2.}{And this is the fourth sentence.---which I want numbered 2.}
\mitemxx{This is the fifth sentence.---which I want numbered 3.}{This is the last sentence.---which I want numbered 3.}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]